# How to add CSS to the module?

Tags: theming, 8

I am very new to Drupal. I have an html form and I want to create a module that take the html of the form and create a table in the database and saves the form values in database.

what i have done i have created a form with form api (with `buildForm` method) my form is being rendered and i have converted it into Twig template (it is being shown in twig template), but first my CSS is not getting loaded.

My library file: `mymodulename.libraries.yml`

```
bootstrap:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
  js:
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once

global-components:
  Version: 1.x
  css:
    css/baselayout.css: {}
    css/form.css: {}
    css/wisdom.css: {}

  js:  
    js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js: {}
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Comment: I removed the second unrelated question (about database input), please ask separate questions separately, after researching yourself first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS lives one level further down in a libraries file; under `system`, `module` or `theme`. e.g.:

```
bootstrap:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
  js:
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Comment: i tried this also

Comment: That's the answer to your question (_how to add css to module in drupal 8_), beyond that I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: hi Clive please help me how to pass action attribute in twig form.